# AWS lambda function give network error with EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

My aws lambda function stop working after adding EFS file system.
First I created EFS
[image]
the security group in EFS is as follow
[image]
and access point, please check attached screen shot
[image]

then create aws lambda, during the aws lambda function, i chose a role
[image]
The role is as follow
[image]
The VPC settings is as follow
[image]
The security group of VPS is
[image]
Till this point hello lambda function is working.
[image]

But as I add EFS it stopped working and say 'Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error'

Comment: I see that you are attaching the default security group to the Lambda. You would want to make sure the security group has port `2049` opened for EFS. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-filesystem.html

Comment: in default VPC security group inbound rule is set to all traffic, so i think it will allow 2059

Comment: You probably would want to add a screenshot for the SG rules as well to your questions.

Comment: The security group of EFS allows traffic only from another security group (`sg-0fcf...`) which is not the one attached to the Lambda (`sg-0dd37...`).